# make yields “commands commence before first target” error

Tags: makefile

I'm new to linux driver dev.

I'm writing helloworld driver.

here is the code:

```
#define MODULE
#define __KERNEL__
#include <module.h>
int init_module() 
{
 return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
 return;
}
```

and here is makefile:

```
    CC=gcc
    MODFLAGS:= -O3 -Wall -DLINUX
    module.o: module.c
    $(CC) $(MODFLAGS) -c module.c
```

But when I run make command I have the following:
makefile:3: *** “commands commence before first target” error

whats wrong?

Comment: Are those spaces on the left margin in the makefile? Or tabs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the leading tabs in the makefile, from every line that isn't a *command*:

```
CC=gcc
MODFLAGS:= -O3 -Wall -DLINUX
module.o: module.c
    $(CC) $(MODFLAGS) -c module.c
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this wasn't the case for you, I encountered the same error message with a different reason. So I am answering here as well so that it may aid people in the future when they encounter the error message but the reason isn't as obvious as in your case.

Here's a minimal example to provoke the error condition by merely having a file with an equal sign in its name match the `$(wildcard)` (obviously here for demonstration purposes I am matching *only* file names with a `=`). Strictly speaking it doesn't matter what method you use to retrieve the names for the `$(FILES)` variable.

```
FILES := $(wildcard ./*=*)

.PHONY: all

define foo
all: something-$(1)
something-$(1): $(1)
    cat $$^ > $$@
endef

$(foreach goal,$(sort $(FILES)),$(eval $(call foo,$(goal))))
```

The problem appears to be in the way the expansion happens  - in this case and it will only happen due to the macro.

Anyway, I was stumped when I ended up with this error message while the make file itself - also according to version control - hadn't changed. Until it dawned on me that there must be some circumstantial reason for the problem then. May it help the future person in search for an answer.